# How to create a document file with the data from the backend?

Tags: flutter, dart, file, document, quill

I have a user name, age, and locality from the backend. Now, I want to create a file or print the details in a specific format. I also have an organization image to be inserted in the file. How can I achieve this?

For Example,

[image: Sample Image]

Above the name, the image has to be inserted.

I have tried this with the [Quill Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) but can't able to create a document.

this is my code:

```
Future<void> downloadingOpdCard({required int index}) async {
    quill.QuillController controller = quill.QuillController(
        document: quill.Document.fromJson(jsondata),
        selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0));
    Directory dir = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/MedBook");
    PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.storage.status;

    try {
      if (permission.isDenied) {
        Permission.storage.request();
      }
      if (await permission.isGranted) {
        if (!dir.existsSync()) {
          dir.createSync(recursive: true);
          File file = File("${dir.path}/sample.doc");
          print(file.absolute);
          if (file.existsSync()) {
            file.deleteSync();
            file.writeAsString(controller.document.getPlainText(0, 300));
          } else {
            file.writeAsString(controller.document.getPlainText(0, 300));
          }
        } else {
          File file = File("${dir.path}/sample.doc");
          print(file.absolute);
          file.writeAsString(
              controller.document.toDelta().first.data.toString());
        }
      } else {
        print("Permission Denied");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check this awesome package if you need formatting. https://pub.dev/packages/pdf It is very easy to create pdfs in it and it shares a similar syntax to flutter so it is very easy to use.